# C# get text from file between two hashes

Tags: c#, streamreader

In my C# program (at this point) I have two fields in my form. One is a word list using a listbox; the other is a textbox. I have been able to successfully load a large word list into the listbox from a text file. I can also display the selected item in the listbox into the textbox this way:

```
private void wordList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          string word = wordList.Text;
          concordanceDisplay.Text = word;
     }
```

I have another local file I need to get at to display some of its contents in the textbox. In this file each headword (as in a dictionary) is preceded by a #. So, I would like to take the variable 'word' and search in this local file to put the entries into the textbox, like so:

> ```
> #headword1
>     entry is here...
>     ...
>     ...
> #headword2
>     entry is here...
>     ...
>     ...
> #headword3
>     entry is here...
>     ...
>     ...
> ```

You get the format of the text file. I just need to search for the correct headword with # before that word, and copy all info from there until the next hash in the file, and place it in the text box.

Obviously, I am a newbie, so be gentle. Thanks much.

P.S. I used StreamReader to get at the word list and display it in the listbox like so:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\...\\list-final.txt");
       string line;
       while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           MyList.Add(line);
       }
       wordList.DataSource = MyList;
```

Comment: How large is your large word list?  Does it all fit into memory at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string getSection(string sectionName)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Path\To\file.txt");
    string line;
    var MyList = new List<string>();
    bool inCorrectSection = false;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            if (inCorrectSection)
                break;
            else
                inCorrectSection = Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^#" + sectionName + @"($| -)");
        }
        else if (inCorrectSection)
            MyList.Add(line);
    }
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, MyList);
}

// in another method
textBox.Text = getSection("headword1");
```

Here are a few alternate ways to check if the section matches, in rough order of how accurate they are in detecting the right section name:

```
// if the separator after the section name is always " -", this is the best way I've thought of, since it will work regardless of what's in the sectionName
inCorrectSection = Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^#" + sectionName + @"($| -)");
// as long as the section name can't contain # or spaces, this will work
inCorrectSection = line.Split('#', ' ')[1] == sectionName;
// as long as only alphanumeric characters can ever make up the section name, this is good
inCorrectSection = Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^#" + sectionName + @"\b");
// the problem with this is that if you are searching for "head", it will find "headOther" and think it's a match
inCorrectSection = line.StartsWith("#" + sectionName);
```

Comment: Instead of calling substring on each line, why not just look for "#" + word :) Also use line.Equals("#" + word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) instead. Finally I would index the dictionary file for faster lookup.

Comment: I only call substring on the # lines.  You could do it either way, using substring was just the first I thought of.  If the asker wants a CurrentCultureIgnoreCase comparison, that's a good way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am confused here: `inCorrectSection = line.Substring(1) == sectionName;`. It appears you are applying the substring value to the variable `inCorrectSection`, which is boolean. I must be missing something.

Comment: That could also be written `inCorrectSection = (line.Substring(1) == sectionName);`.  That is, I'm comparing `line` after its first character to `sectionName`.  The result of that is a boolean, which I then store in `inCorrectSection`.

Comment: inCorrectSection = (line.Substring(1) == sectionName); This might be clearer. The parenthesis is a comparison between the line and the word you are looking for. It is a boolean which is then affected to isCorrectSection.

Comment: oooh. gotchya. I think I have it figured out. One last thing. The target field (which displays the entries) is not a listbox, but a textbox. I think `.DataSource` is only for listboxes. Besides, the `getSelection()` method returns a list, but I need it to return text for the textbox. When I apply all this, I get an error saying you cannot convert an IList into a string.

Comment: Ok, from your example, I thought you were looking for a list of the lines.  I'll change it to join the lines into a single string.

Comment: sorry...getting another error at this line `return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, MyList);`. It says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>'".

Comment: You forgot to change the return type of the method from `IList<string>` to `string`.

Comment: No need to use a list, just use a StringBuilder(or a string) and concatenate inside the loop.

Comment: That's another option, yes, but IMO using a `List` and `string.Join` makes for the most readable code - otherwise you end up with things like `if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);`.

Comment: it looks to be doing what it is supposed to. it doesn't yet display anything in the textbox, but that might be because there is other text after the headwords. So it is not just `#headword1`, but it is `#headword1 - other text here`. I think that may be breaking it. any ideas?

Comment: yes...I think that is breaking it, because `line.Substring(1) == sectionName` is returning false, which never changes the value of `inCorrectSection` so it adds the line to the list.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.  I've edited the answer to fix it by using `Split` instead of `Substring`.  There are a few ways to do this, e.g. just check that the string StartsWith the right value, or split like I did, or regex.  I chose splitting because it makes concise and relatively readable code, while not being too flexible or inflexible with what will pass the "test".  The biggest drawback to this method is that sectionName can't contain spaces or hashes.

Comment: It works. To fix the `line.Substring(1) == sectionName`, I just added `inCorrectSection = line.Substring(1, a) == sectionName;` after finding the length of the `sectionName` string and putting it in a like so: `int a = sectionName.Length;`. Again, thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: That's essentially the same as using `line.Substring(1).StartsWith(sectionName)`, except that in your current code, if sectionName is longer than the line, an exception will be thrown.  Here's another option, using Regex: `inCorrectSection = Regex.IsMatch(line, "^#" + sectionName + @"\b");`

Comment: I've edited the answer with a few different ways to do that line.  Depending on what a sectionName can be and what the separator can be, pick the best from the list for your solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
var sectionLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName) // shortcut to read all lines from file
    .SkipWhile(l => l != "#headword2") // skip everything before the heading you want
    .Skip(1) // skip the heading itself
    .TakeWhile(l => !l.StartsWith("#")) // grab stuff until the next heading or the end
    .ToList(); // optional convert to list
```