# Fetching lines between two different line of StreamReader in a List in c#

Tags: c#, list, streamreader

I have a StreamReader `reader`where i have content as below

> some text here 
> Test text here 
> TEST_START,,,,,, 
> Test,1,text
>  Test,2,text
>   Test,3,text 
> Test,4,text 
> Test,5,text
>
> TEST_STOP,,,,,, 
> some text here

I need to fetch the lines between `TEST_START` and `TEST_STOP` in a list.I used below code but don't know i missed something 
 [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778911/c-sharp-get-text-from-file-between-two-hashes) taken from here:

```
string start_token = "TEST_START";
string end_token = "TEST_STOP";
string line;
bool inCorrectSection = false;    
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.StartsWith(start_token))
    {
        if (inCorrectSection)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(line.StartsWith(end_token))
        {                           
            inCorrectSection = true;
        }
    }
    else if (inCorrectSection)
        myList.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what did you try?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you asking us to write code for you or do you have some code to show what have you attempted to solve your problem?

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to change the logic slightly:

1. When you find the start line, set your variable to true (and continue the loop).
2. When you find the end line, set your variable to false (and continue the loop, or break the loop if you only expect to have one section to capture).
3. If your variable is true, capture the line

For example:

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.StartsWith(start_token))
    {
        // We found our start line, so set "correct section" variable to true
        inCorrectSection = true;
        continue;
    }

    if (line.StartsWith(end_token))
    {                           
        // We found our end line, so set "correct section" variable to false
        inCorrectSection = false;
        continue; // Change this to 'break' if you don't expect to capture more sections
    }

    if (inCorrectSection)
    {
        // We're in the correct section, so capture this line
        myList.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Rufus, its working fine. I am able to get those lines.